# Generic database return function using MSSQL

Tags: java, sql

I am writing (have written) a sort of generic database query function.  Since it will be called from various places with different field names, and maybe different columns, I want to make a list of Map.  So I thought I would get the metadata, find each column name and get the column values.  But this is throwing an out ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
        try {
            ResultSet rs = Query.OpenQuery(conn, sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
                int cnt = md.getColumnCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
                    String col = md.getColumnName(i);
                    String val = rs.getString(col);
                    col = col.toLowerCase();
                    map.put(col, val);
                }
                res.add(map);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            throw new KDTException("Could not query directconnectionsubmittracking", e1);
        }
```

As I step through it, the value of cnt is 2.  It throws the exception the first iteration when i is 0, which should not be out of bounds.  Not sure exactly why it is throwing an out of bounds exception.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. passing queries sounds like your system is rife for SQL injection attacks. You should rarely query based on an sql statement; usually it's an sql statement with question marks in it, + all the argument passed separately, using PreparedStatement to tie these together. Otherwise you can't avoid SQL injection security issues.
2. There are libraries that have thought about this and done it. Specifically JDBI and JOOQ; i'd give those a read before you continue reinventing this particular wheel.
3. Most things in JDBC are bizarrely 1-indexed, not 0-indexed. So, it's `md.getColumnName(i + 1)` or possibly adjust the loop to start at 1 and use `<= cnt` instead of `< cnt`.
4. Re-querying the column headers for *every* returned row is silly; any given resultset will not change headers between calls to `rs.next()`. Do it once, not once-per-row.

Comment: Thanks.  It is true that this is rife for SQL injections but no one will be using it except me and it gets the data from a screen that we have control of.  In general it is not a good idea at all.  And I see your point about getting the column names each time.  Makes sense